# jqGrid: How to add edit and delete button in every row with form editing enabled?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have a grid like the following image:

[image: Image for adding edit and delete button in every row like in the black box]

Currently, I have add, edit, delete button in the footer. I need to have "edit" and "delete" button in each row. When I will click on edit button in each row, It will show edit form and when clicked on Submit, It will save data to the database.

My code looks the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, { altRows:true });
        $("#list_records").jqGrid({
            url: 'ajaxELearningFetchTableData.php?table=GET_TRAINING_TYPE',
            //url: 'server.php',
            editurl: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ["TRAINING TYPE ID", "TRAINING TYPE NAME", "REMARKS"],
            colModel: [
                {
                    label: 'TRAINING TYPE ID',
                    name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    editable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: "text",
                    editoptions: {readonly: "readonly"},
                    width: 40
                },
                {
                    label: 'TRAINING TYPE NAME',
                    name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                    index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                    width: 120,
                    editable: true, // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                    editoptions: {size: 50, maxlength: 80},
                    editrules: {required: true, maxlength: 80},
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: "text",
                    // set options related to the layout of the Edit and Add Forms
                    formoptions: {
                        colpos: 1, // the position of the column
                        rowpos: 2, // the position of the row
                        label: "Training Type Name:", // the label to show for each input control  
                        elmsuffix: "(*)"

                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'REMARKS',
                    name: 'REMARKS',
                    width: 140,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'textarea',
                    editoptions: {rows: 3, cols: 45},
                    formoptions: {
                        colpos: 1,
                        rowpos: 3
                    }
                }
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows: true,
//            width: auto,
//            height: auto,
            width: 1000,
            height: 300,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            caption: "Training Type Information",
            sortname: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            emptyrecords: "No Records to Display.",

            //footerrow: true,
            pager: "#perpage"
        });

        $('#list_records').navGrid('#perpage',
                // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
                        {edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false},
                // options for the Edit Dialog
                        {
                            height: 'auto',
                            width: 620,
                            editCaption: "Edit Training Type",
                            url: 'ajaxSaveTrainingType.php',
                            recreateForm: true,
                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                            afterComplete: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },

//                            afterShowForm: function(form) {
//                                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
//                            },
                            afterSubmit: function () {
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true];
                                //location.reload(true);
                            }
                        },
                // options for the Add Dialog
                        {
                            height: 'auto',
                            width: 620,
                            addCaption: "Add Training Type",
                            url: 'ajaxSaveTrainingType.php',
                            closeAfterAdd: true,
                            recreateForm: true,
                            afterComplete: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
//                            afterShowForm: function(form) {
//                                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
//                            },
//                           
                            afterSubmit: function () {
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true];
                                //location.reload(true);
                            }
                        },
                // options for the Delete Dailog
                        {
                            height: 'auto',
                            width: 620,
                            addCaption: "Delete Training Type",
                            url: 'ajaxSaveTrainingType.php',
                            closeAfterAdd: true,
                            recreateForm: true,
                            //rp_ge, postdata
                            onclickSubmit: function () {

                                var sel_id = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                var trainingTypeId = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID');
                                return {tTypeId: trainingTypeId};


                            },
                            afterComplete: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
//                            afterShowForm: function(form) {
//                                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
//                            },
                            afterSubmit: function () {
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true];
                                //location.reload(true);
                            }
                        });
            });
```

Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to show add and edit form in the middle of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the column, which uses `formatter: "actions"` with `formatoptions: { editformbutton: true }` properties. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop), then you can use `template: "actions"`:

```
{ name: "act", template: "actions", formatoptions: { editformbutton: true } }
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) as an example.

In case of usage old jqGrid (version <=4.7) you can add the column with the following properties for example:

```
{ name: "act", formatter: "actions", formatoptions: { editformbutton: true },
    width: 54, align: "center", fixed: true, hidedlg: true, resizable: false,
    sortable: false, search: false, editable: false, viewable: false }
```

Comment: It is working. But grid is not loading with updated data and editform is not being closed after submit.  And editform dialog is being popped up with small width.

Comment: @Jahirul: You should write more clear what you mean. First of all do you mean my demo or some your code? For example Edit dialog will be closed and data will be updated in my demo. Which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? How you specify the options of the form editing in case of usage `formatter: "actions"` or `template: "actions"` in *your* demo?

Comment: I am using jqGrid version of 4.6.0

Comment: { name: "act", 
                    formatter: "actions", 
                    formatoptions: { 
                        editformbutton: true 
                    },
                    width: 54, 
                    align: "center", 
                    fixed: true, 
                    hidedlg: true, 
                    resizable: false,
                    sortable: false, 
                    search: false, 
                    editable: false, 
                    viewable: false  
                }

Comment: 1) I recommend you to update from jqGrid 4.6.0 to free jqGrid 4.13.5. Free jqGrid is backwards compatible to jqGrid 4.6.0, but it allows dramatically reduce the JavaScript code and improve the performance of it. I recommend you to examine the code of my demo: `formEditing` option, for example. 2) If you don't can update then you have to use `editOptions` property of `formatoptions`. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more details.

Comment: Problem solved. Actually I was making mistake. I was writing 'editOptions' outside 'formatoptions'. Taking 'editOptions' inside 'formatoptions' solved my problem. Thanks @Oleg  for your help.